# CGO did not generate header file at Mac OS

Tags: go

I run the below code at `Win 10` and got both `lib` and `lib.h` generated, tried the same at `Mac` but only `lib` got generated, and the `lib.h` not appeared!!

```
// file: lib/go.mod

module hasan/lib

go 1.14
```

And

```golang
// file: lib/main.go
package main

import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world")
}

func main() {}
```

And made the build as:

```sh
$ go build -buildmode=c-shared
```

No error show up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th error was due to missing:

```golang
import "C"
```

In the `lib/main.go` this is the one responsible about generating the proper header file `lib.h`

**Example**

Create go file `lib.go`

```golang
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export HelloWorld
func HelloWorld() {
    fmt.Printf("hello world from GO\n")
}

func main() {}
```

Compile the above as:

```sh
go build -o lib.so -buildmode=c-shared lib.go
```

Then `app.c` as:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include "lib.h"

int main(){
    HelloWorld();
    printf("Hello from c\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And compile it (and build executable) as:

```sh
cc -o output app.c lib.so
```

And call the `output` as:

```
Hasans-Air:Documents hajsf$ ./output
hello world from GO
Hello from c
```